# Does $x^3+y^3=\frac{1}{\sqrt2}$ have points inside $(x,y): x^2+y^2 \leq 1$

Tags: analytic-geometry, curves

How can I tell that the curve $x^3+y^3=\frac{1}{\sqrt2}$ have points on the compact set $(x,y): x^2+y^2 \leq 1$ ?

Can I tell somehow right away, instead of solving the system of equations?

Comment: I think there are three points inside $$x^2+y^2\le1$$

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner - There are a lot more than three points with $x^3+y^3=\frac{1}{\sqrt2}$ in the set $x^2+y^2\le 1$ though there are indeed  three real solutions on $x^2+y^2=1$.  See [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+x%5E3%2By%5E3%3D1%2Fsqrt(2)+and+x%5E2%2By%5E2%3D1)

Comment: You probably got started from the fact that $$\sqrt{\frac{x^2+y^2}2}\le\sqrt[3]{\frac{|x|^3+|y|^3}2},$$ so that for points on the unit circle $|x|^3+|y|^3\ge\frac1{\sqrt2}$. But that means by scaling this inequality that all points with $|x|^3+|y|^3=\frac1{\sqrt2}$ lie inside the closed unit disk.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of the points on $x^3+y^3=\frac{1}{\sqrt2}$ is $\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt[6]2},0\right)$

Since $0 \lt \frac{1}{\sqrt[6]2} \lt 1$, you can say this point satisfies $x^2+y^2 \leq 1$

Answer (score 4):

You can tell right away by guessing. Simply setting one of the variables to $0$ reveals that $(2^{-1/6},0)$ is on the cubic curve and in the disc. Setting $x=y$ also reveals that $(1/\sqrt2,1/\sqrt2)$ is on the cubic and *on* the disc boundary.

Answer (score 4):

It should be clear that the point $\left(\frac1{\sqrt2},\frac1{\sqrt2}\right)$ belongs to both sets.

Answer (score 0):

Part of the curve  $$ x^3+y^3= \frac {1}{\sqrt 2}$$ goes true  the disk $x^2+y^2=1$ and the intersection is uncountable.

The intersection passes through the point $(0, 2^{-1/6})$ which is inside the disk.

Answer (score 0):

Given a curve of the type $$x^3+y^3=a,$$ with $a$ real, we may write this as $$y={(a-x^3)}^{1/3},$$ which defines $y$ as an everywhere continuous function of $x.$ Furthermore, as $x\to\pm\infty,$ we have that $y\to\mp\infty.$ Thus, the curve divides the plane into two regions. Furthermore, we have $y= a^{1/3}$ when $x=0.$ Thus, we only need to have $$-1\le a^{1/3}\le 1$$ in order to have some point of the cubic within the closed unit disk.

If $a=\frac{1}{\sqrt 2},$ then $|a^{1/3}|$ is indeed less than unity since $2^{1/6}>1,$ which is true since $2^{1/2}>1.$ By the continuity of the involved curves it follows that there are infinitely many points of the cubic not without the disk.